# Issues creating table with js : order <tr> and <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write a very simple js script to dynamically create a table.
This is what i use:

```
$("#resultsTable").append("<tr>")
for (var i=0; i<statsHolder.length; i++){
    $("#resultsTable").append("<td>" + statsHolder[i] + "</td>");
}
$("#resultsTable").append("</tr>")
```

statsHolder is an array that contains the data i want to display in my table.
The issue i'm facing here is that the html code created is not ordered like i want it to be. Instead of this:

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

This is what i got:

```
<tr></tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<tr></tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
```

I guess that my problem is that the code after  my loop for is executed before the loop starts.
What should i do about it?
Thanks for you help :)

Comment: When you append an element, you append the complete element. You're not just adding the open (or closing) tags to the page, which is why you're seeing that behavior.

Answer (score 3):

do it, using string instead

```
var table = "<tr>";

for (var i=0; i<statsHolder.length; i++){
   table += "<td>" + statsHolder[i] + "</td>";
}

table += "</tr>";
$("#resultsTable").append(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$("#resultsTable").append("<tr>").attr('id', 'sampletable');

for (var i=0; i<statsHolder.length; i++){

    $("#sampletable").append("<td>" + statsHolder[i] + "</td>");

}
```

And if you want to use it for multiple rows try this:

```
for (var j=0; j< 10; j++) { 

    $("#resultsTable").append("<tr>").attr('id', 'tablenamerow-'+j);

    for (var i=0; i<statsHolder.length; i++){

        $("#tablenamerow-"+j).append("<td>" + statsHolder[i] + "</td>");

    }
}
```

Here you can change the limit of `var j` to the number of rows you want to generate. I just put number 10 arbitrarily. And if you have multiple tables using this set the `tablename` unique for each table also.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go with that, seems really clean and efficient!

Comment: this will not work with multiple calls, will create multiple rows with the same id

Comment: @konkked Updated code for multiple rows issue. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery will only insert VALID html into the tree. You're not building a string of html - you're modifying the live DOM tree, which means your final `.append('</tr>')` is completely invalid. You cannot "append" a closing tag.

And generally speaking, doing repeated DOM manipulations like you are, in a loop, is inefficient. It's easier to build a string of HTML and then append that as a single block, saving you having to rebuild/modify the DOM tree over and over.

```
html = '<tr>';
for(...) {
    html += '<td>' + foo + '</td>'
}
html += '</tr>';
$('#resultsTable').append(html);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it makes a lot more sense for me now :)

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the `<td>` to the table instead of the row
Keep the `<tr>` in a variable and append the `<td>` elements to it:

```
var tr = $("<tr/>").appendTo($("#resultsTable"));
for (var i=0; i<statsHolder.length; i++){
    $("<td/>").text(statsHolder[i]).appendTo(tr);
}
```

You also don't need to close the `<tr>` or the `<td>` since the first row creates the entire element

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is resolving the tag before you are appending to the new row, you need to create a row then append to that row, then append to the table

```
   var statsHolder = [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    var me = $('<tr></tr>');
    for (var i=0; i<statsHolder.length; i++){

        me.append("<td> " + statsHolder[i] + "</td>");
    }
  $("#resultsTable").append(me);
```

see plunk of example

http://plnkr.co/edit/sAnWY3?p=info

Answer (score 0):

You can create your `<tr>` element and keep trace of it in a temporary variable without adding necessary an ID attribute to it

```
var myTr = $('<tr>');
$("#resultsTable").append(myTr)
for (var i=0; i<statsHolder.length; i++){
    myTr.append("<td>" + statsHolder[i] + "</td>");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stL42ak3/